# SMTP Server Mail Alerts using TLS and authentication

Tags: linux, ssl, smtp, mailx, mail-command

i am a bit new in using SMTP server Alert configurations on AIX 7.1 OS . i am currently using below syntax which is running fine :

mail -s "Subject" "abc@test.com" < /path/to/my/input.txt

but we are now migrating our SMTP server with authentication and TLS enable but i am unable to do so . please guide me what am i doing wrong :

echo "This is the message body and contains the message" | mailx -v -s "This is the subject" -S smtp=smtp://newsmptp.test.com:25 -S smtp-use-starttls -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user="temp" -S smtp-auth-password="Abc#123" -S ssl-verify=ignore "abc@test.com"

regards
Ammar Barya

Comment: when i use the 2nd command i get following error :
mailx: Not a recognized flag: S